# designing a cross gable roof with a doorway

Tags: construction, roofing

I am trying to attach a gable roof perpendicular to an existing one,but looking for some help in joining two perpendicular/cross gable roofs with a one door headroom. It is because the existing gable roof has a higher slant, so a doorway can be created only after cutting through the rafters of existing gable roof.

I am looking for guidance to best tackle the project. Many contractors mentioned that easiest course is to remove the roof on one side and completely reframe with new gable roof, but it is very expensive. I am wondering if it can be done by removing couple of rafters and creating adequate support so as not weaken existing structure.

In the picture below I want to make a doorway through direction shown by arrow. Due to the slope, it can only be done by cutting through the roof.

thanks again

[image]

Comment: A roof has many functions to handle besides just keeping rain/snow out.  Holding the walls together, preventing the wind from blowing it off, snow load are just a few.  A structural engineer might be better to plan what you need(they don't get money from construction cost), and they know local conditions.  Might need one anyway for the permits.

Comment: If this doorway is going to open directly into a room, there will be a _lot_ of rafters that need to be cut to make way for the wall. In that case I see a definite case for tear off the whole roof and do it right. If it's going to lead into a hallway that leads into a new room, then you might get away with cutting just a couple of rafters & heading them off. I admire the DIY spirit, but an engineer will ensure this doesn't collapse and kill people. Get the plans certified, then do the work yourself.